# Object prototype method.submethod = function() get this of main class

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, methods, prototype

I'm having trouble accessing the parent `this` of the javascript class.

```
Slider.prototype.method.submethod = function(){
   var self = this;
}
```

How can I access the `this` of the parent, Slider class? I want `method` to only describe the target, and not make it an object itself.

Is there any way of doing this without passing it as a parameter?

Comment: The value of `this` is determined by how a function is **called** - you can use `.call()`, `.apply()`, and/or `.bind()` to arrange for `this` to be set the way you want it.

Comment: I'm calling it directly: `this.method.submethod();` Should I be using a call wrapper?

Comment: Got it to work. Add this as an answer and I'll accept it. Thank you!